# In Avengers, how was everyone able to look at the Tesseract with naked eyes?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers-2012, captain-america-the-first-avenger

In *Captain America: The First Avenger* movie, the Tesseract was highly luminous. Only Red Skull was able to look at it with naked eyes. Others needed to use googles.

In *The Avengers* movie, what made the Tesseract so dim like an ordinary object that everyone was able to look at it with their naked eyes?

Comment: Is it clear in the first Captain America film that they *need* to use goggles, or is it just fear/reverence for the Cube? e.g. the caretaker “It is not for the eyes of ordinary men”.

Comment: @alexwlchan But, the movie shows Tesseract highly luminous. You can see bright blue light coming out of it.

Comment: Actually, I think the only time anyone needed to wear goggles was when Dr. Zola wore some while applying power to the Tesseract during his experiment. Many of the Hydra troops wear goggles as part of their uniform, so that doesn't apply.

Comment: "highly luminous" is not necessarily dangerous or mean that one is unable to safely look at it without goggles. It certainly can be , but I haven't seen anything indicating that it's *dangerous* to look at it without protection. Some bright lights are fine to look at for short times, but you want to avoid looking at them for long periods. Scientists studying it might want goggles for long periods of work on it while Red Skull wouldn't worry since he's only focusing on it for a short time.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: “You can see bright blue light coming out of it.” Which I think demonstrates in and of itself that human beings can look at bright blue light with no eye protection (aside, perhaps, from 3D glasses).

Answer (score 7):

The scientists and engineers in *Captain America* are very cautious, and with good reason-- it's the first time anyone has subjected the Tesseract to scientific investigation, and they've already learned some hard lessons from, e.g. radium. For all we know, Hydra loses a few technicians while learning how to extract energy from it, and Howard Stark almost kills himself playing with a speck of *that*, and he's handling it with waldoes from behind shield glass. Red Skull is bolder because, well, he's Red Skull.

Seventy years later, the scientists know a lot more (about the Tessaract and radiation in general) and have much more confidence that they know how to handle it safely (and look how well that turns out). After the theft, Loki's slaves can handle it without precautions because he doesn't care about their long-term welfare, and at the end Dr. Selvig and others dispense with precautions because *aliens are invading.*

Comment: How does your answer explain luminosity?

Comment: @SachinShekhar: It doesn't; I was talking about goggles for safety, not for comfort. All I can suggest on apparent luminosity is that things look brighter in darkness: in *Captain America* the Tessaract appears in a gloomy Norwegian crypt, in a gloomy Bavarian castle and on the ocean floor (apart from the scene where it's actually *going critical*), while *The Avengers* places it in brightly lit 21st century labs and then on top of a skyscraper at noon on a sunny day.